# NOOB custom module event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node and have created a custom module.

My custom module simple defines a class with a single method.

I would like to be able to call this method once from the defined class object.

I would also like to be able to reference a variable in my main code from this class method.

In the "open" method I have two console.log commands. With the 2nd producing an error "ReferenceError: thisVar is not defined". If I comment out the 2nd console.log that relates to the error "open" is printed.

How can I reference thisVar from the class method?

**Edit1**
I understand from the responses that "thisVar" is outside of the scope of the class and therefor unavailable. With this being the case why does "thatVar" work as it is also defined outside of the class? Is the scope relative to the module and not the class?

This is my main js code:

```
"use strict";

const Door = require('door');
const mydoor = new Door("green");

var thisVar = 1;

console.log(mydoor.colour);
mydoor.open();
```

This is my "door" module:

```
"use strict";

var thatVar = 2;

class Door {

  constructor(colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  open() {
    console.log("open");
    //console.log(thisVar);
    console.log(thatVar);
  }

}

module.exports = Door;
```

Comment: Did you mean `mydoor.open()`? I also don't see `thisVar` defined anywhere. The `thisVar` in door and the `thisVar` in main are not associated in any way at all.

Comment: Typo fixed thanks. Can the class method reference thisVar in main at all?

Comment: No, they have no association at all. If anything you could pass `thisVar` through he constructor like `colours`

Answer (score 1):

`thisVar` is not in the scope of the `door` module. The `Door` somehow needs to access to `thisVar`, so I would pass to the constructor.

```
class Door {
  constructor(colour, thisVar) {
    this.colour = colour;
    this.thisVar = thisVar;
  }
  open() {
    console.log('open');
    console.log(thisVar);
  }
}
module.exports = Door;
```

Main js:

```
const door = require('door');
const myDorr = new Door('green', 1);
```

Comment: So the variable scope is restricted to the module and not the class itself. I always imaged the require statement to be an include statement that simply places the code within the main code.

Answer (score 1):

**Door.js**

```
// Door.js
   'use strict';

module.exports = class Door {

   constructor(colour) {


  this.colour = colour;
  }
  open(ThisVar) {
    console.log("open");
      if(ThisVar)
    console.log(ThisVar);
  }
   }
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

   var Door = require('./Door.js');

   var someone = new Door("pink");
 var a=7;
someone.open(a);
someone.open();
```

[image]